# How to disable Macbook's trackpad to not zoom?

Tags: macos, macbook, zoom, touchpad

I went to Mac's Preferences for TrackPad and uncheck `Zoom` already, but if I go to Chrome or Firefox, and use two fingers to zoom, the page will still zoom in or zoom out.  It is troublesome because sometimes I mean to move the mouse cursor or scroll up or down but instead zoom in or out of the page instead, so hoping to disable it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To disable the zoom of a web page you want to uncheck the "Pinch" action in the Trackpad Preference Pane as Screen Zoom is a different feature (For zooming in the entire interface). Myself I have it disabled for this exact same reason - I trigger it accidentally far too often.

Comment: yeah, it happens far too often than the real need to zoom in or out.  I think I need to zoom in or out a few times a day at most, but trigger this by it being too sensitive almost 30 times a day.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to completely disable the "pinch" action, you might want to look into [this](http://cubeyellow.blogspot.com/2009/01/mac-book-pro-trackpad-zooming-and.html). It will only disable this action in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and a few other programs.